# How can I merge all the changes from 1 branch to another

Tags: git

In git, I have a branch with multiple commits, can I merge all the changes in that branch to another brach that I just created?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

In a terminal:

```
$ cd path_to_you_rep
$ git checkout new_branch
$ git merge old_branch
```